# For loop..if - Return true only after all intervals pass

Tags: javascript, if-statement

A bit of a simple question, yet I can't figure it out. Perhaps I should be using a different method. I want to return true only after all the intervals in the for loop are run and pass the condition. However, as I have my code written, the return to true or false is done after the initial value of the loop. 
The code tests if the letter 'z' is in the string 3 or less indices after a letter 'a'.
How can I fix/optimize my code?

```
function nearbyAZ(str) {
    var aIndex = [];
    if (str.length == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if (str[i] == 'a') {
            aIndex.push(i);
        }
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < aIndex.length; j++) {
        if (str.indexOf('z') <= aIndex[j] + 3 && str.indexOf('z') >= aIndex[j]) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}

console.log(nearbyAZ("abfz")) //true
console.log(nearbyAZ("abannz")) //should return true but false is returned before the second 'a' can be tested
console.log(nearbyAZ("a")) //false
console.log(nearbyAZ("z")) //false
console.log(nearbyAZ("za")) //false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Keiwan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37282941/5220640) will work if you want to only return true if there is a "z" within three characters after every "a".  otherwise it will return false.

If you want your function to return true if there is a "z" after any "a", but not necessarily every "a" then you need to make a slight modification to that code:

```
for (var j = 0; j < aIndex.length; j++) {
    if ((str.indexOf('z') <= aIndex[j] + 3) && (str.indexOf('z') >=    aIndex[j])) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

This will return true if it ever happens that "z" occurs withing three letters after an "a".

The issue with your original code was the 'if else' statement.  For every "a" you were checking if there was a "z" and then if there wasn't you were returning false, without checking the other "a"s.  So your first "a" was always going to force you to return a value and you never checked the following a's

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it is not working, is because you have to put your return false outside the loop.

When it hits a return it will go out of the function.

```
function nearbyAZ(str) {
    var aIndex = [];
    if (str.length == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if (str[i] == 'a') {
            aIndex.push(i);
        }
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < aIndex.length; j++) {
        if (str.indexOf('z') <= aIndex[j] + 3 && str.indexOf('z') >= aIndex[j]) {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the last loop to:

```
for (var j = 0; j < aIndex.length; j++) {
    if (!(str.indexOf('z') <= aIndex[j] + 3) || !(str.indexOf('z') >= aIndex[j])) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

So if within you loop your condition is `false` (at any point) you `return false`. If everything goes well and you exit the loop without returning false then you can `return true`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version, which uses the second parameter of [**indexOf()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to determine where the next **z** is in relation to an **a**:

```js
function nearbyAZ(str) {
  var i, idx;
  
  for(i = 0 ; i < str.length ; i++) {
    if(str[i] === 'a') {
      idx = str.indexOf('z', i);  //returns -1 if not found
      if(idx > -1 && idx <= i + 3) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
} //nearbyAZ

console.log(nearbyAZ("abfz")) //true
console.log(nearbyAZ("abannz")) //true
console.log(nearbyAZ("a")) //false
console.log(nearbyAZ("z")) //false
console.log(nearbyAZ("za")) //false
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using regex?

```
function nearbyAZ(str) {
  return str.search(/a\w{0,2}z/) !== -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, a function with [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and an appropriate callback with `this` object.

It works with a single loop and without `indexOf`, or other lookup mechanism.

```js
function nearbyAZ(str) {
    return str.split('').every(function (l, i, aa) {
        if (l === 'a') {
            this.lastA = i;
            this.hasZ = false;
        }
        if (l === 'z') {
            this.hasZ = i - this.lastA <= 3;
            return this.hasZ;
        }
        return i + 1 === aa.length ? this.hasZ : true;
    }, { lastA: -10, hasZ: false });
}

function print(s) {

    document.write(s + ': ' + nearbyAZ(s) + '<br>');
}

print("abfz");   // true
print("abannz"); // true
print("a");      // false
print("z");      // false
print("za");     // false
```